# Invert digits from columns in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Is it technically possible to flip numbers from all cells in a column without a plugin ?

For example, a two column spreadsheet with

```
Ref, Weight
3300, 500
3200, 500
```

Would become

```
Ref, Weight
0033, 500
0023, 500
```

Comment: @BenN `3200` **reversed** is `0023` as per his example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub flipper()
    Dim r As Range, s As String

    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "@"
        r.Value = StrReverse(r.Text)
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

If you wish to avoid macros and the cells contain only digits and you are willing to use a "helper column", then with digits in column **A**, in **C1** enter:

```
=TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1)*10^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)))-1)),REPT("0",LEN(A1)))
```

and copy down:
[image]

From [T. Valko's response](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/488462-formula-reversing-numbers-text.html)

Comment: Looks promising, testing this now !

Comment: Poor pentium anniversary CPU took a big headshot in term of CPU usage, but it works as expected used multiple cores, very efficient, thank you very much ! (Tested the VBE solution)

Comment: @Zulgrib  .................Glad to Help..............